# PyQt5: How to increment a variable every second with Timers?

Tags: python, oop, timer, pyqt5

I have an assignment where I essentially need to make a copy of Cookie Clicker, and part of the assignment is to increase the click count every interval of time (I chose 1 second because its easier) by a certain amount of clicks. I have pretty much everything done, except that I can't seem to get this part to work, and have already tried many different methods of making Timers.

The code that I'm using is here:

**Timer Code-**

```
    self.started = False

    self.timer = QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateCount)
    self.timer.start(1000)

def clicked(self):
    def updateCount():
        if self.started:
            self.timesClicked += 1
            self.label.setText("Pats: " + str(self.timesClicked))
            self.label.adjustSize()

            self.timer.start(1000)
        else:
            self.started = True
    for count in range(0,1):
        self.timer.singleShot(self.timerDelay, updateCount())
```

**Full Code-**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import time
import sys

class Clicker(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Clicker, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 500, 400)
        self.timesClicked = 0
        self.clicksPerSecond = 0
        self.timerDelay = 1000

        self.tool1Cost = 15

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt")
        self.label.setText("Pats: " + str(self.timesClicked))
        self.label.move(10, 120)

        self.cpsLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.cpsLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt")
        self.cpsLabel.setText("CPS: " + str(self.clicksPerSecond))
        self.cpsLabel.move(10, 150)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-image: url(cat_.jpg); }")
        self.button.resize(100,120)
        self.button.setText("Pet Me!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.tool1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.tool1.resize(100, 30)
        self.tool1.move(120, 0)
        self.tool1.setText("Add Tool1. Cost: " + str(self.tool1Cost))
        self.tool1.adjustSize()
        self.tool1.clicked.connect(self.toolOne)

        self.started = False

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateCount)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def clicked(self):
        def updateCount():
            if self.started:
                self.timesClicked += 1
                self.label.setText("Pats: " + str(self.timesClicked))
                self.label.adjustSize()

                self.timer.start(1000)
            else:
                self.started = True
        for count in range(0,1):
            self.timer.singleShot(self.timerDelay, updateCount())

    def toolOne(self):
        if self.timesClicked >= self.tool1Cost:
            self.timesClicked -= self.tool1Cost
            self.clicksPerSecond += 1
            self.label.setText("Pats: " + str(self.timesClicked))
            self.cpsLabel.setText("CPS: " + str(self.clicksPerSecond))

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Clicker()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What should happen after the button click? Should the timer go on indefinitely? Besides that: 1. the argument of a `singleShot` must be callable, but you're using the return value of a function; change that line to `self.timer.singleShot(self.timerDelay, updateCount)`; 2. `for count in range(0, 1)` is meaningless; 3. when you paste your code, you *must* ensure that it's [correctly formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362): don't ask us to "ignore" it, it only makes it harder to understand what that code does or even if you made indentation errors.

Comment: @musicamante There are two buttons, the first one just increases the number of times clicked, and the second button (which is where i have my problem) is supposed to increase the # of Times Clicked by a certain value each second (by 1 in this case) once it is "purchased". And yes, the timer should go on indefinitely

Comment: So, can't you just start the time only as soon as the second button is clicked? Note that you can use [`isActive()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#isActive) to check if a timer is running, so there should be no need for a `started` variable, nor an anonymous function. Also, in your code you are trying to connect the timeout signal to `self.updateCount`, but that function doesn't exist.